# Neo4j: Java API to compute intersection multiple properties

Tags: neo4j, graph-databases, java

I'm very new in using Neo4j and have a question regarding the computation of intersections of nodes.

Let's suppose, I have the three properties A,B,C and I want to select only the nodes that have all three properties.

I created an index for the properties and thus, I can get all nodes having one of the properties. However, afterwards I have to merge the IndexHits. Is there a way to select directly all nodes having the three properties?

My second idea was to create a node for each property and connect other nodes by relationships. I can then iterate over all relationships and get for each property a list of nodes which are connected. But again, I have to compute the intersection afterwards.

Is there a function I miss here, since I suppose it's a standard problem.

Thanks a lot,
Benny

Answer (score 4):

Do you also have the values you look for? You would start with the property that limits the amount of found nodes most.

```
MATCH (a:Label {property1:{value1}})
WHERE a.property2 = {value2} AND  a.property3 = {value3}
RETURN a
```

For the Java API and lucene indexes:

```
gdb.index().forNodes("foo").query("p1:value1 p2:value2 p3:value3")
```

Lucene query syntax

Comment: Hi Michael,
thanks for your fast reply.

You are using Cypher for retrieving the nodes. Sorry, I stated only in the title that I want to know, if there is also an elegant way using the Java API. In particular for the second case where my properties are stored as separate nodes. What would you suggest (fastest solution) to find the nodes which are connected to all of these three property nodes?